# How to get Angular Push Notification in Android Native App using Capacitor?

Tags: angular, firebase, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

I'm developing Angular progressive web application, when I run the application using `ng serve` it's working well in browsers with background notifications on service worker.

But the same functionality is not working with mobile application which is created with Capacitor build tools using `npx cap add android`.

My **firebase-service-worker.js** file :

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': '65358642427'
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {

  var notificationTitle = JSON.parse(payload.notification).title;
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: JSON.parse(payload.notification).body
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the purposes of registering and monitoring in background for push notifications from Firebase Angular APP, Use the Push Notification API for Capacitor in an Ionic + Angular application.

1. Prepare your Firebase account and create Android application in Firebase console with a package ID, example package : `com.example.myapp`
2. Download the `google-services.json` file from Firebase console and paste it to your project root directory.
3. Create Android project in your directory using capacitor : `npx cap add android`

Finally handle the notification listener in your app component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {
  Plugins,
  PushNotification,
  PushNotificationToken,
  PushNotificationActionPerformed } from '@capacitor/core';

const { PushNotifications } = Plugins;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})

export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Initializing HomePage');

    PushNotifications.register();

    PushNotifications.addListener('registration', 
      (token: PushNotificationToken) => {
        alert('Push registration success, token: ' + token.value);
      }
    );

    PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError', 
      (error: any) => {
        alert('Error on registration: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    );

    PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived', 
      (notification: PushNotification) => {
        alert('Push received: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
      }
    );

    PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationActionPerformed', 
      (notification: PushNotificationActionPerformed) => {
        alert('Push action performed: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
      }
    );
}
```

**Note** : When you receive a notification from Firebase this app will not be triggred but the `pushNotificationActionPerformed` will be triggred when you click the notification and redirected to APP.

https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/push-notifications

Answer (score 2):

When you do `npx cap add android` you create a native Android project.

For Android projects you have to use the native push implementation, not the web one, Capacitor provides a plugin for it. https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/push-notifications